# Convert from HKEY to string, C++

Tags: c++, windows, string, registry

I working with Win registry and in one function I need to take from `HKEY hKey` full path of current 'folder'.

For example, hKey 'work' with section '`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\KB968369`'. But i can only take last name of subSection '`KB968369`'.
Have anyone some thinking about method like 
' `string FunctionConvert(HKEY hKey)` '  wich return fullPathName of hKey?

Not necessary string type, it may be also TCHAR, char or another text type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function. Since you create the `HKEY`, and at some point have access to its full path, you are expected to remember that information.

You'll simply have to remember the path rather than throwing it away.

Comment: I need this ConvertFunction in another func - there I take ALL subsections and values of current hKey. It seems very difficult to have some parametr wich saves current path in this way

Comment: What is hard about remembering a string?